# Fedora SSHd not starting after upgrade to 35

Tags: linux, ssh, security, fedora, sshd

today I've upgraded a VM server mounting Fedora 25 to Fedora 35.
I performed a step upgrade skipping 1 release at a time 25-->27-->...-->33-->35.
I had zero problems until the last upgrade, here at the reboot I lost my sshd service.
I reached the console using virt-viewer and analyzed the problem:
On service start, I get an error: `code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION`.
Testing with `sshd -t` I get the following message:

```
/etc/crypto_polices/back_end/opensshserver.config: line6: Bad configuration option:  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
/etc/crypto_polices/back_end/opensshserver.config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I'm not an expert and I found no answer to this problem online.
While in this situation if I try to ssh into my server I get a connection refused.

So I tried to remove the configuration file, start again the service and everything is up and running with no issue.

At this point, I'm concerned about security issues, I mean, I know that if something like crypto policies are implemented there should be a good reason and should not be disabled.

I have two questions to end this post:

1. What policy does ssh implements if it's not using the one specified by the crypto policies? Where are the "default" ones specified?
2. I would love to solve the problem in a more sound way, not just deleting a file and hoping that everything it's ok, do you have any suggestions? Or pointers to understand better the problem and find a solution on my own?

Comment: Post your configuration file

Comment: Are you sure that's not `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config`?
 I'm going to operate on that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really adventurous update sequence, and I'm kind of proud that it came so close to working flawlessly.

I think what's happening here is that the security policy is updated to the latest version, but for some reason, openssh is not. OpenSSH upstream made an incompatible change in this configuration option in [OpenSSH 8.5](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5) in late 2021. (The old name still works, but the new one does not.)

What do you get from the command `rpm -q openssh-server crypto-policies`? As of right now, I get:

```
openssh-server-8.7p1-3.fc35.x86_64
crypto-policies-20210819-1.gitd0fdcfb.fc35.noarch
```

But the important things are: I'm relatively certain that your `crypto-policies` package is *at least* version `20210615`, and I'm guessing that `openssh-server` is, for some reason *before* `8.5p1`.

Assuming my guess is right, that's the root problem to solve. But, alternately, I believe that a workaround would be to edit the config file to replace `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` with the older name `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` — which should also still work going forward at least for a while, as OpenSSH has retained the old name too for compatibility.